# Which class can I have to put byte code for getting time to get connection?

Tags: derby

I want to insert byte codes to collect the elapse time to get the database connection. But I don't know which class get the connection in derby.  I tried putting the byte code like the following classes.

```
AsmUtil.add(reserved, "org/apache/tomcat/dbcp/dbcp/BasicDataSource", "getConnection");
AsmUtil.add(reserved, "org/apache/derby/jdbc/ClientBaseDataSourceRoot", "getConnection");
AsmUtil.add(reserved, "org/apache/derby/jdbc/BasicClientDataSource40", "getConnection");
```

But, I can't catch the place where derby try getting the database connection.

Comment: Derby is open source. Surely your best approach is to start by seeing how to modify the source code, rather than leaping straight into bytecode? In fact you probably don't even need to do that - it's quite likely it can be done by judicious subclassing.

Comment: I've deleted the bytecode-asm tag because it doesn't become an ASM problem until you know what you want to do with ASM.

Comment: @MichaelKay Thanks for the reply. I added the tag for the attention of those people who have already experienced using asm. I added every place related this and debugged. But I can't catch the point.